# NSUserDefaults vs SQLite3. NSUSerDefaults immutable?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, nsuserdefaults

Pardon this, I know there's are answers out there for these question already. But I would like to know whether is my approach of choosing NSUserDefaults for my implementation correct.

I am trying to do a 'favourite list' to be displayed on `UITableView` where I will need to save about 5 objects for each list. So I figured I will have `NSDictionary` within a `NSArray` for my tableView dataSource.

I was taken aback from using `NSUserDefaults` when I read "Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable". Is there a way I can manipulate the objects stored? For example, read the array from `NSUSerDefaults` then add new objects onto it and store it back.

`NSUserDefaults` looks very easy to use.

EDIT
Can we insert mutable objects in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read object from NSUserDefaults like this:

```
//Read from NSUSerDefaults
NSMutableArray* favListArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"listArray"]];

//Add objects to array
[favListArray addObject:@"NewObject1"];
[favListArray addObject:@"NewObject2"];

//Overwrite the NSUSerDefaults valueForKey:@"listArray"
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:favListArray forKey:@"listArray"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: So, I create an mutableArray from userDefaults(array) and then add it back? I thought we can't insert mutable objects in? Or they will do an auto conversion to non-mutable objects if we inserted  mutable objects? Which is why they only return non-mutable objects. Why would they wanna do that?

Comment: From developer documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html "Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string as the value for "MyStringDefault", the string you later retrieve using stringForKey: will be immutable." So I initialized mutable array from immutable array..

Comment: It am interested to know the reason why it doesn't return mutable objects though.

Comment: @MaTakazer when you write to NSUserDefaults, it ends up in a property list file. Property list files don't track whether a value was mutable or immutable.

Comment: I see. Are we able to insert mutable objects then? Or we will have to do the conversion to nonmutable first?

Comment: You can add mutable objects NSMutableArray* arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arr addObject:@"One"];
    [arr addObject:@"Two"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:arr forKey:@"Array"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Array"]);

Answer (score 0):

You can call `mutableCopy` to get a copy of of an object if it is part of a Mutable/Immutable cluster such as NSArray/NSMutableArray NSDictionary/NSImmutableDictionary, etc.

So get the object out of the dictionary - call mutableCopy on it and you can modify it and save it back.

Remember that this method has a copy in its name, so you need to release the copy when you are finished with it.